# Elastic beanstalk and httpd.conf file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a rails app to an elastic beanstalk application and I'm running into a Phusion Passenger timeout when I try to start my app.

`The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-d3fc9cf2].`

I read I can make the timeout longer by modifying the httpd.conf file but I'm going crazy trying to find it. I've ssh'd into my ec2 instance and I cant find a httpd/apache folder or file anywhere.

Here's my /etc folder where I'm expecting an httpd folder:

```
[etc]$ ls
acpi               crontab                  fstab        issue           man.config      pm           rpc           sudoers
adjtime            cron.weekly              gai.conf     issue.net       maven           popt.d       rpm           sudoers.d
aliases            csh.cshrc                gcrypt       java            mime.types      ppp          rsyslog.conf  sudo-ldap.conf
aliases.db         csh.login                gemrc        jvm             mke2fs.conf     printcap     rsyslog.d     sysconfig
alternatives       dbus-1                   ghostscript  jvm-commmon     modprobe.d      profile      rwtab         sysctl.conf
anacrontab         default                  gnupg        krb5.conf       motd            profile.d    rwtab.d       system-release
asound.conf        depmod.d                 group        kshrc           motd.rpmsave    protocols    sasl2         system-release-cpe
at.deny            dhcp                     group-       ld.so.cache     mtab            racoon       screenrc      terminfo
audisp             DIR_COLORS               grub.conf    ld.so.conf      my.cnf          rc           securetty     tmpfiles.d
audit              DIR_COLORS.256color      gshadow      ld.so.conf.d    nanorc          rc0.d        security      udev
bash_completion.d  DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor  gshadow-     libaudit.conf   NetworkManager  rc1.d        services      update-motd.d
bashrc             dracut.conf              host.conf    libreport       networks        rc2.d        shadow        vimrc
blkid              dracut.conf.d            hosts        libuser.conf    nsswitch.conf   rc3.d        shadow-       virc
cfn                dumpdates                hosts.allow  localtime       ntp             rc4.d        shells        wgetrc
chkconfig.d        e2fsck.conf              hosts.deny   login.defs      ntp.conf        rc5.d        skel          X11
cloud              elasticbeanstalk         image-id     logrotate.conf  openldap        rc6.d        smrsh         xdg
cron.d             environment              init         logrotate.d     opt             rc.d         ssh           xinetd.d
cron.daily         ethers                   init.d       lvm             pam.d           rc.local     ssl           yum
cron.deny          exports                  inittab      magic           passwd          rc.sysinit   statetab      yum.conf
cron.hourly        filesystems              inputrc      mail            passwd-         resolv.conf  statetab.d    yum.repos.d
cron.monthly       fonts                    iproute2     mailcap         pki             rmt          sudo.conf
```

Also tried this but nothing:

```
[etc]$ ps -ef | grep apache
ec2-user  3987  3543  0 02:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
```

What am I doing wrong here? My app was running fine the other day, but since some updates I pushed out I'm having this issue. I reverted them and it's still timing.

Comment: Can you please explain how you ssh'd your aws elastic beanstalk server for your following rails app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk Rails stacks run nginx, not Apache. Try:

```
$ ps -ef | grep nginx
```

Also, your app directory should be under /var/app/current

Hope this helps.